# Quick way to reshape

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reshape data from long to wide format R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format-r)

With:

```
day <- c(1, 1, 2, 2)
prod <- c(1, 2, 1, 2)
cost <- c(20.1, 17.7, 15.2, 23.3)
record <- data.frame(day=day, prod=prod, cost=cost)

record
  day prod cost
1   1    1 20.1
2   1    2 17.7
3   2    1 15.2
4   2    2 23.3
```

What is a good (quick) way to reshape the data as:

```
       day_1 day_2
prod_1  20.1  15.2
prod_2  17.7  23.3
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about the duplicate as I didn't find the right word to search for similar questions. Thank you all for answering!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `dcast` from the `reshape2` package has the simplest syntax:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(prod ~ day, data=record, value.var='cost')

  prod    1    2
1    1 20.1 15.2
2    2 17.7 23.3
```

However, this question has been asked many times and will likely be closed quickly.

Answer (score 6):

We can also use `xtabs`

```
xtabs(cost ~ prod + day, data = record)

    day
prod    1    2
   1 20.1 15.2
   2 17.7 23.3
```

Comment: +1 No need for me to duplicate your Answer. Cleaning up.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use `tapply` - the sum function doesn't matter as you have unique values:

```
> tapply(record$cost,list(record$prod, record$day), FUN=sum)

     1    2
1 20.1 15.2
2 17.7 23.3
```

Comment: This may not work as in a particular day there may be some product missing, but works excellently other than that. Thanks!

Comment: Should work fine, you'll just end up with `NA` in the cell where you have a missing data. Which seems like a good behaviour to me.